# PHP - How to get a synonyms list for an hebrew word?

Tags: php, synonym

I'm writing a php code.
I want to show to the user a synonymslist for each hebrew word.
How can I do it?

I tried this way:

```
$word = new COM("word.application") or die ("Could not initialise MS Word object."); 
$synonyms = $word->Application->SynonymInfo('שמח', 1037);
```

but I don't know how to continue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try something simple like `var_dump($synonyms)` to see what you get back?

Comment: Does the COM library get loaded successfully?

Comment: The COM library seem to be loaded successfully, I didn't get the die message.

Comment: I tried var_dump, print_r etc. I got the message 'com_safearray_proxy' and I didn't know what to do with it. I tried: $synonyms[0] etc. but no succeed :-(

Comment: Anyone have a sample code? Or maybe another way to get synonyms list for hebrew word? PLEASE